# CENTOS Network Loopback file is down: Cant connect to Internet

Tags: networking, centos6

I accidentally deleted the loopback interface file so my eth files aren't coming up when I reboot my machine after typing ifconfig -a

The loopback file shows as down, how do I start it?

I tried editing the network scripts file for eth0 but I get an error saying no file exists.

Please help, the objective is to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question,

nano /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo

or vi, but nano will work for someone newer to Linux. If you think you can use vi, then run this:

vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo

Then paste the following:

```
DEVICE=lo
IPADDR=127.0.0.1
NETMASK=255.0.0.0
NETWORK=127.0.0.0
# If you're having problems with gated making 127.0.0.0/8 a martian, # you can change this to something else (255.255.255.255, for example)
BROADCAST=127.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=loopback
```

Save the file and exit. Reboot or run the following:

service network restart

or if you are using systemd

systemctl restart network.service

reputation please.